# kth root of a number goes to 0

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have $(a_n)$ where $a_n > 0, a_n \to 0$. I want to show $\sqrt[k]{a_n} \to 0$. My idea is to use the squeeze theorem. Obviously $0 < \sqrt[k]{a_n}$. What function of $a_n$ might be a good candidate for an upper bound?

Comment: why don't you use that $a_n \to 0$??

Comment: Did you prove continuity of $x\mapsto \sqrt x$ yet?

Comment: Just use the definition of convergence directly. I think that's the easiest way.

Comment: Squeeze thereom may not be best strategy.  But for $0 < a_n < 1$ we have $\sqrt[k]{a_n} < \sqrt[k+1]{a_n}$.  AlexR comment of continuity is a good one.

Comment: Problem is, I haven't formally worked on continuity so I guess it's off the table for now.

Comment: Or a proof by contradiction .  if the root doesn't go to zero then there is always an epsilon that some root a_n will be greater than.  so some a_n will alwasy be greater than epsilon to the k.  So a_n doesn't go to 0.

Comment: $$\forall\epsilon>0\qquad\exists N\qquad\forall n\geqslant N\qquad 0\leqslant a_n\leqslant\epsilon^k$$ hence $$\forall\epsilon>0\qquad\exists N\qquad\forall n\geqslant N\qquad0\leqslant\sqrt[k]{a_n}\leqslant\epsilon$$

Comment: I finally worked with the definition of convergence per Arthur's suggestion and got what Did wrote above.

Comment: Oh,  did's direct proof is pretty much more direct than my proof by contradict.  D'oh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squeeze theorem isn't a good idea as it isn't obvious what a good upper function should be-- at least not with circular reasoning. (You could use $0 < a_n < \sqrt[k]{a_n} < \sqrt[k+1]{a_n} < 1$.)

But if $ \sqrt[k]{a_n} \not \rightarrow 0$ then there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ so that for any $M$ there will be *some* $n > M$ where $\sqrt[k]{a_n} \ge \epsilon$.  So for any $M$ there will always be *some* $n > M$ where $a_n \ge \epsilon^k > 0$.  So $a_n \not \rightarrow 0$.

Indeed for $a_n > 0$, $a_n \rightarrow 0 \iff \sqrt[k]{a_n} \rightarrow 0$.  You can prove the converse, $\sqrt[k]{a_n} \rightarrow 0 \implies a_n \rightarrow 0$ via the squeeze theorem if you like.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the fact that $x\mapsto x^k$ is continuous, use this:

$$a_n \searrow 0 \Rightarrow (\sqrt[k] a_n)^k \searrow 0 \stackrel{\text{cont. of } x\mapsto x^k}\Rightarrow \sqrt[k] a_n \searrow 0$$

On a $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-level, a proof looks like this:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $N$ be such that $0 < a_n < \varepsilon^k$ for all $n \ge N$. Then
$$0 < \sqrt[k]a_n < \sqrt[k]\varepsilon^k = \varepsilon \qquad \forall n \ge N$$
Thus we have shown $\sqrt[k]a_n \to 0$. This uses the monotonicity of $x\mapsto \sqrt[k]x$